# When trying to install an rpm file I get error message : error: can't create transaction lock on /usr/lib/sysimage/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)

Tags: centos, yum, root, rpm

I'm having problems with `yum` and I am trying to re-install it. I've download `yum.3.2.0-40-el6.centos.noarch.rpm`.

When I try:

```
$ rpm -ivh yum.3.2.0-40-el6.centos.noarch.rpm
```

I get:

> error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)

I tried running `su -` and I'm getting this error:

> -bash: su: command not found`

I get the same "permission denied error" if I try to uninstall `yum` and force ignore dependencies (without forcing to ignore dependencies, it fails uninstall with a few dependencies).

Comment: Are you root or using `sudo` when you run this command?

Comment: @slm, I am not able to get either sudo or su to work (see comment to your answer). Are these the only ways to work as root?

Comment: What distro is this?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /bin/su` ? command not found seems like you have bigger issues than mere yum.

Comment: if this is off-topic in Unix&Linux SE, where would it be on-topic ?

Answer (score 26):

This error:

> error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)

... would appear to be you trying to perform an `rpm -ivh ...` command as a user other than root.

You'll need to run it like so:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh yum.3.2.0-40-el6.centos.noarch.rpm
```

Also make sure that you're in the directory where you happened to download the `yum..rpm` file. Perhaps you downloaded as your regular username and are now attempting to install it as root. Note that when you become root you're typically changed directories into `/root`.

If `su -` is broken for whatever reason you can also become root like so:

```
$ sudo -i
```

Comment: I am confused on the sudo and su commands. `su -` gives (see above), and `sudo -i` gives `sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo su` before and it works :)

Comment: if `su -` returns "su: command not found", this won't work either. The real problem is why and how /bin/su disappeared.

Comment: it works for me.

Answer (score -3):

Try running `$ sudo rm /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock`

Comment: Why not? We are certainly on a container nowadays... So you may do nasty things like that, if it works.