# Installing python 3 on CentOS 6.9 without sudo

Tags: centos, python3, pip

Python 3 installation exits without installing zlib and pip. How can I fix this?

edit 2: I cannot use sudo.

edit:

I followed this [guide](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-install-and-configure-python-on-a-hosted-server). After running 'make' the installation exited with:

```
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel      
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma              
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter           
readline              zlib                                     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.'

File "/home/sites/3b/4/40b84bb780/Python-
3.6.4/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
File "/home/sites/3b/4/40b84bb780/Python-
3.6.4/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
default_pip=args.default_pip,
File "/home/sites/3b/4/40b84bb780/Python-
3.6.4/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
File "/home/sites/3b/4/40b84bb780/Python-
3.6.4/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [altinstall] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you post the installation log and the command you ran?

Comment: I followed this[link](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-install-and-configure-python-on-a-hosted-server/)  After running 'make altinstall' the installation exited with:

Comment: You may complete your question, it's more efficient then comments.

Comment: I've edited the question. I added part of the log.

Comment: Installing software without `sudo` often requires compiling from source.

Answer (score 1):

zlib is needed to complete the installation.

Regarding edit2:
You may try with RPM. Download the zlib-devel rpm and then run `rpm -ivh package.rpm`

To install it on CentOS:
`sudo yum install zlib-devel`

Then run the make command again.

Comment: I do not have sudo access. It's a shared hosting server.

Comment: Can you try the edit with rpm?

Comment: I had tried to do that but I got an error - 'error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)'. according to this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125706/why-cant-i-install-packages-with-rpm-i-get-transaction-lock) , you need to use it with sudo?

Comment: This means you also need sudo access for rpm command. It's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below; `make altinstall`to try to get around any sudo permission needed to replace the default python binary file in /usr/bin/python

```
yum install gcc
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0a1.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.7.0a1.tgz
cd Python-3.7.0a1
./configure
make altinstall
```

Comment: yum is sudo restricted so first line won't run

Comment: Sounds like you need to reach out to your system admin.  Probably a reason for the account you are using to not has sudo access.