# RHEL-7.4 Linux rpm file Installation error

Tags: permissions, rhel, software-installation, rpm

I tried to install rpm file in RHEL-7.4 Linux using:

```
# rpm -i xxx.rpm
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.5WIuFR: line 9: /etc/init.d/xxx-driver: Permission denied
```

What is this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Congratulations on your first question! Do take a quick look at the formatting I applied, and the extra wording I removed. (People can click on your profile to see your list of questions & answers).  Do also take our [excellent tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to become more familiar with the site.

Comment: Your question might be the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125706/why-cant-i-install-packages-with-rpm-i-get-transaction-lock?rq=1 -- RPM's will need to be installed as root. Were you the root user when you ran the `rpm` command?

Comment: Please post the complete error message. It seems possible that you've posted a partial error message. Thank you.

Comment: My doubt is why rpm-tmp.5WluFR file not created.  I executed this comment by root user only.

Comment: please add the content of /etc/init.d/xxx-driver, with more logs.

Answer (score 0):

The package is executing a pre- or post-install script in `/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.5WIuFR`; on line 9 of that script, it is attempting to execute `/etc/init.d/xxx-driver`, but that latter file does not have execute permissions set.